how to bind zeromq (libzmq.dylib) with mql 5 on macOS
I am trying to write a trading bot using C++ in vscode which will be connected to metatrader 5 via binding (zeromq) on macOS. But after I installed brew install zeromq and also moved the zmq.h to :
" /Users/kiro/Library/Application Support/net.metaquotes.wine.metatrader5/drive_c/Program Files/MetaTrader 5/MQL5/Include/include "
and file libzmq.dylib to :
"/Users/kiro/Library/Application Support/net.metaquotes.wine.metatrader5/drive_c/Program Files/MetaTrader 5/MQL5/Libraries"
I am unable to bind the server, can someone help me?
For now I only use the example code to try to connect to the server via binding. When I compile this code, there is no error. But when I drag the script in Metatrader 5 to the chart I get those errors:
'''
#import "libzmq.dylib"
int zmq_ctx_new();
int zmq_socket(int context, int type);
int zmq_bind(int socket, string endpoint);
int zmq_recv(int socket, uchar &data[], int len, int flags);
int zmq_send(int socket, uchar &data[], int len, int flags);
int zmq_close(int socket);
int zmq_ctx_term(int context);
#import

void OnStart() {
    int context = zmq_ctx_new();
    int socket = zmq_socket(context, 4); // ZMQ_REP
    zmq_bind(socket, "tcp://*:5555");

    uchar data[];
    ArrayResize(data, 256);

    while (true) {
        zmq_recv(socket, data, 256, 0);
        Print("Received request: ", CharArrayToString(data));

        string reply = "World";
        uchar replyData[];
        StringToCharArray(reply, replyData);
        zmq_send(socket, replyData, StringLen(reply), 0);
    }

    zmq_close(socket);
    zmq_ctx_term(context);
}

'''
When I compile it, there is no error. But when I drag the script on chart I get those errors:
2024.06.22 18:18:35.410 mql5 (EURUSD,M15) cannot load 'C:\Program Files\MetaTrader 5\MQL5\Libraries\libzmq.dylib' [193]
2024.06.22 18:18:35.413 mql5 (EURUSD,M15) cannot call 'zmq_ctx_new', 'libzmq.dylib' is not loaded
2024.06.22 18:18:35.413 mql5 (EURUSD,M15) unresolved import function call
on other hand code in c++ in vscode looks like this
''''
#include <zmqpp.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    try {
        zmqpp::context context;
        zmqpp::socket socket(context, zmqpp::socket_type::req);
        std::cout << "Connecting to server..." << std::endl;
        socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

        std::string request = "Hello, MT5";
        zmqpp::message message;
        message << request;
        std::cout << "Sending message: " << request << std::endl;
        socket.send(message);

        zmqpp::message reply;
        std::cout << "Waiting for reply..." << std::endl;
        socket.receive(reply);
        std::string reply_str;
        reply >> reply_str;
        std::cout << "Received: " << reply_str << std::endl;
    } catch (const zmqpp::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "ZeroMQ Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Standard Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Unknown Exception" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

''''
and after building the code control + shift +b and ./main in the terminal I get this:
Connecting to server...
Sending message: Hello, MT5
Waiting for reply...
I

/Users/kiro/Library/ and /Users/tuanhungbuivan/Library/ are different paths. Please check that first

my bad it was, kiro in both, but still error exist

is it linux? sad truth is that most development for MT is under windows. if win - try to copy libzmq.dylib into the main directory (C:\..\libraries) and restart MT
